# user defined function for glm in r not working

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I want to execute logistic regression for each predictor seperately using glm. Total predictors are 50 and churn_flag is target variable and What I have done so far as:-

```
lapply(c('A1','A2','A3','A4',.................'A50'),

   univariate_logistic <- function(var) {

     formula    <- as.formula(paste('churn_flag ~ ', var))
     res.logist <- glm(formula, data = split_train, family = binomial)

     summary(res.logist)
     })`
```

After running a function when I passed a variable name inside function as,

```
univariate_logisitic(A1)
```

it gives error as,

```
Error in univariate_logistic(A1) : 


could not find function "univariate_logistic"
```

Comment: The error was including `univariate_logistic <-` before the function when used inside `lapply`. You can either use a previously defined function by name or you can use an anonymous function as is most typically done with `lapply`.

Comment: @42- got it..Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your function is not found in the current workspace, because you are defining the function inside of the `lapply` context. It should work if you write the function, outside that block of code. This should give you an idea. Just as an advice and in order to improve readability, I always write the function as another entity; that way you can reuse your code. So your current code could be written as:

```
univariate_logistic <- function(var) {
  cat("Current value: ", var , "\n")
}

lapply(c('A1','A2','A3','A4','A50'),
       univariate_logistic   
)
```

> **This prints the following output:**

```
Current value:  A1 
Current value:  A2 
Current value:  A3 
Current value:  A4 
Current value:  A50
```